# Are bitcoin futures daily settled at T+1 or is there another mechanism?

Tags: futures, bitcoin, cme

As in the title, are bitcoin futures daily settled at T+1 or is there another mechanism? Both CBOE and CME

Comment: If the answer provided by @Ezy solves what you are looking for, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Futures settle at their expiry, not daily. Futures mark-to-market daily and their mtm impacts your margin account. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. I have another question. What is the settlement mechanism of margin account?

Comment: Thanks for upvoting if you find the answer useful. Also if you have another question it is better to ask a new question rather than putting in comments